# jQuery - Cycling through child elements

Tags: jquery, children

I have a series of select boxes within a table like so:

```
<tr>
<td><select></select></td>
<td><select></select></td>
<td><select></select></td>
<td><select></select></td>
</tr>
```

With about 10 rows.

I'm trying to reset all of the select boxes in the row to a default value, but having trouble with the syntax, can anyone help?  This is what I have at the moment, but it dosen't seem to be working:

```
$(row).children('td > select').each().val('0');
```

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: the .each() part is superfluous. Does it work if you leave that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to simply select a default value, this should work (not tested):

```
$('select', row).each(function() {
    this.selectedIndex = 0; //or whatever the index you want
});
```

Using $('select', row) is a bit faster than the selector you have, so is accessing directly the objects property, instead of using the jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `each` at all, jQuery handles applying the change to all matched elements for you:

```
$(row).children('td > select').val('0');
```

Note that that sets the *value* of the select box, e.g., makes the option with the matching `value` selected. It's not the same as setting the *index* of the selected option (another of the answers here shows you how to do that). Using an example with non-numeric values makes the distinction a bit clearer:

HTML:

```
<div id='characters'>
<select name='favorite'>
<option value='fred'>Fred Flintstone</option>
<option value='barney'>Barney Rubble</option>
<option value='wilma'>Wilma Flintstone</option>
<option value='betty' selected>Betty Rubble</option>
</select>
<select name='secondchoice'>
<option value='fred'>Fred Flintstone</option>
<option value='barney selected'>Barney Rubble</option>
<option value='wilma'>Wilma Flintstone</option>
<option value='betty'>Betty Rubble</option>
</select>
```

jQuery call to change both of those to 'wilma':

```
$('#characters select').val('wilma');
```

...or (perhaps more sensibly for that *particular* example) to having no options selected at all:

```
$('#characters select').val('');
```